# Get corner items in current CSS grid layout, expanding on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-grid

I'm using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 250px)` to keep grid items `250px` wide but automatically adjust number of row-items according to screen-width. Now I want that when I hover over an item, it expands taking a bit of its sibling's space, with its sibling getting shrunk. By `console.log()`, I found `nextElementSibling` that can be used. So I'm thinking of something like-

```
function expand(card){
    card.setAttribute("style","width: 300px;");
    card.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("style","width: 200px");
}
```

```
function restore(card){
    card.setAttribute("style","width: 250px;");
    card.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("style","width: 250px");
}
```

This seems pretty bad (I guess!) because I need to manage corner items separately and hence need to know the current number of items in a row. Also, when I hover over a card, the card does expand but because of `repeat(auto-fit,250px)`, the card intersects its sibling because the individual cells remain fixed (`250px`).
How can I solve the issues? Or any better suggested solutions?
[Here](https://github.com/sapinder-pal/DashBoard-Theme-Switcher.github.io) is my git repository.

Edit 1-
As to clarify my issues:

1. How to manage the corner items, i.e., for an item in the right corner I want its previous sibling shrink; not the next.
2. The cells remain fixed, i.e., the expanding item intercepts the shrinking item's border-

[image]

becomes

[image]

So how to deal with this behavior caused by `auto-fit,250px`?

Comment: provide your html code.

Comment: provided my git repository link in the question

Comment: what is issue in this solution ?

Comment: I edited the question to state issues briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly tried to solve it using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px,auto));` and a different size of child elements, but in's too unstable and not working that way. But I don't think the `grid` is require for this task. The easiest way I see how this should be solved - using good old JavaScript (+jQuery) and `flex`. Although the right way will be resize all elements in a single row, not only nearest siblings of a hovered element. Try it on any screen size.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* defines main digits */
  let boxWidth = $('#box').innerWidth();
  let itemOuterWidth = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
  let itemInnerWidth = $('.item').innerWidth();
  SetSeparators(boxWidth, itemOuterWidth);

  /* refresh main digits ater page resize */
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.item').css({
      "flex": ""
    });
    boxWidth = $('#box').innerWidth();
    itemOuterWidth = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
    itemInnerWidth = $('.item').innerWidth();
    SetSeparators(boxWidth, itemOuterWidth);
  });

  $('#box').on('mouseover', '.item', function(e) {
    GetElementsPosition($(this).index('.item'), $(this), boxWidth, itemOuterWidth, itemInnerWidth);
  });

  $('#box').on('mouseleave', '.item', function(e) {
    $('.item').css({
      "flex": ""
    });
  });

});

/* set separator elemet to avoid blocks to jump from row to row while resizing */
function SetSeparators(boxWidth, itemOuterWidth) {
  $('.separator').remove();
  let countRowItems = Math.floor(boxWidth / itemOuterWidth);
  $('<div class="separator"></div>').insertBefore('.item:nth-child(' + countRowItems + 'n+1)');
}

function GetElementsPosition(index, element, boxWidth, itemOuterWidth, itemInnerWidth) {

  /* calculating row items, column position and row position of a current elemet */
  let countRowItems = Math.floor(boxWidth / itemOuterWidth);
  let colPosition = index % countRowItems;
  let rowPosition = Math.floor(index / countRowItems);
  /* exmanpd size of a hovered element in pixels*/
  let expandSize = 50;

  /* counting number of items in a hovered row */
  let currentRowCounter = 0;
  $('.item').each(function(e) {
    let thisIndex = $(this).index('.item');
    let thisRowPosition = Math.floor(thisIndex / countRowItems);
    if (rowPosition == thisRowPosition) {
      currentRowCounter++;
    }
  });

  /* settting each element widht according to it's position in a list and row */
  $('.item').each(function(e) {
    $(this).css({
      "flex": "0 1 " + itemInnerWidth + "px"
    });
    let thisIndex = $(this).index('.item');
    let thisColPosition = thisIndex % countRowItems;
    let thisRowPosition = Math.floor(thisIndex / countRowItems);
    if ((rowPosition == thisRowPosition) && (colPosition == thisColPosition)) {
      $(this).css({
        "flex": "0 1 " + (itemInnerWidth + expandSize) + "px"
      });
    } else if (rowPosition == thisRowPosition) {
      $(this).css({
        "flex": "0 1 " + (itemInnerWidth - (expandSize / (currentRowCounter - 1))) + "px"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        "flex": ""
      });
    }
  });

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background: gray;
  flex: 0 1 250px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 15px;
}

.separator {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify what `...insertBefore()...` line is doing? What does `.item:nth-child` refer to? a single `.item` or all items? Where are you trying to put the separator?

Comment: `insertBefore()` in this case puts `.separator` div before certain `.item` div. Selector `.item:nth-child(5n+1)` means if a sum of an element in one row is 5, we select every `.item` element that is on (5n+1) position. `n` is any number, if n=0, the rule is 5*0+1=1, selecting `.item` element #1 (not #0, because `:nth-child` start to count from 1, not 0). for n=1 the statement is 5*1+1=6. All this means we set a separator before every first `.item` in each row. Why? Because on some screens the elements, while getting smaller, could jump to the previous row. Open console and hover `.item` to see